# Replace plus (+) with dash (-) with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i change the url plus(+) sign to dash(-) in url with mod_rewrite. This is the code i have so far

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /searchpage\.php\?search=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^searchpage\.php$ /searchpage-search-%2.html? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule searchpage-search-(.*)\.html$ searchpage.php?search=$1 [L]
```

This is for a search form that uses $_GET request. This works well only thing is that i want to change plus with dash. I would really appreciated if anyone can help out.

Answer (score 0):

Insert these 2 rules **before** your existing rule:

```
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule "^([^+]*)\++([^+]*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```